# How to underclock/undervolt Ryzen 7950x permanently

Tags: bios, uefi, amd-ryzen, underclock, undervolting

I've tried 2 different methods of undervolting/underclocking but I cannot make them permanent.

As recommended by https://overclock3d.net/reviews/cpu_mainboard/amd_eco_mode_guide_for_am5/1, I tried setting PPT = 142000, TDC = 110000 and EDC = 172000 for 105W TDP in UEFI/BIOS of my ASUS Rog Strix X670E-E motherboard. Looked OK. Problem is, when I stress tested CPU with CPU-Z, there wasn't absolutely any change in the speed or temperatures.

I tried also with Ryzen Master, setting the "manual" profile to 4800 MHz and 1 Volt, and that worked, the performance dropped slightly and temperatures dropped significantly but... that software has a problem - first of all, it pops a warning when you start it and it doesn't apply the profile automatically on system reboot. And the persistent profiles only do a change in BIOS anyway which I already tried so that didn't work either.

So is there a way to apply Ryzen Master profile on reboot, either via command line or any other way or why the BIOS settings above don't produce any effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this myself. The solution is to go to in BIOS the left side - to "My Favorites" option, where the "AMD Eco mode" is offered. Very unintuitive, but it finally works.

Additionally, even though, this is not undervolting, choosing and customizing different Windows power-profiles (such as "Balanced", "Power Saver" etc.), sets the maximum usage of the CPU.

Answer (score -2):

this is because you set your PPT, TDC and EDC way to high, it's usually a 3 number value.

Try PPT 125 TDC 115 EDC 155
Vcore LLC 4
SOC LLC 3
VRM switching 800khz
SOC voltage 1.16v

Negative vcore offset of -50mv and set also a negative frequency offset of -100mhz
This should give you huge boost clocks in games and pull only 125W when rendering aka all core performance.

If this doesn't work, you can increase the negative frequency offset or maybe increase PPT a little.